# Get set photo size from within a nested Facebook api call?

Tags: facebook, api, nested, photos

I am trying to get a list of all the photos posted within a Facebook event and then check if those photos have any comments. I am then searching those comments and comment replies for keywords. If the comments have the right keyword then I am saving the photo information for further processing at a later step.

My question is how can I return a certain photo size within my nested call. 
Here is what I have so far:

`{eventID}/?fields=photos{link,picture,comments{from,message,comments}}`

This returns all the info I need other than the photo is only a thumbnail and I want a larger version of the photo?

I also want to keep it to one nested call if possible.

Thanks for any help you can provide me.

4/29 UPDATE:
I also tried this:

```
{eventID}/photos/?fields=images,link,comments{from,message,comments}`
```

However, this returns all the image sizes related to the photo and I want to be able to choose what size is returned. Is this possible?